# How did Wells lose the Portable Door in the first place? How did it end up where Paul finds it?

Tags: the-portable-door

The inciting incident of *The Portable Door* is that Humphrey Wells loses the magic Portable Door. He has it in the film's prologue scene, because he uses it to trap John Wells in the Nether. It is ultimately found in the Goblins' basement, with the help of Arthur Tanner (in stapler form). Presumably, Humphrey Wells doesn't transmorgrify Arthur Tanner until *after* trapping John Wells and consolidated his power. Dennis also seems generally hesitant to help Humphrey.

This all leads me to believe that it was either Arthur or Dennis who stole the Portable Door and hid it in the basement.

Furthermore, when Paul finds the Door, it is already open to a location, specifically the hallway *right outside* the presentation room for Operation: Fine Print. The occupants of the presentation, including Humphrey Wells, couldn't have easily walked *past* it without noticing—even if it were magically cloaked like the other side of the door was, it seems like they would have walked *into* it just by accident, since it was right there in the hallway. That makes me believe that the Door was only opened to the hallway very briefly before Paul found it.

So who opened the Door, Arthur? (It's shown that the stapler can move around, so I *guess* maybe it/he could activate the Door?) Without Arthur showing Paul where to find the door, he never would have found it in the Goblins' basement, and without the Door being already open, he never would have learned about Humphrey's plot. So was Humphrey's defeat basically orchestrated all by Arthur?

(I've only seen the movie, so I welcome answers that either include more movie details or introduce additional information from the books!)

Comment: There's a movie?

Comment: Yeah, came out in 2023. No idea how it compares to the books but I thought it was a well-done movie. Good score, good pacing and direction.